# Unable to install XML R package in Docker image due to missing R_HOME var

Tags: r, linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I had a docker image that was building successfully for months. However, since Dec 17th I've run into the error shown in the **Jenkins console output** below. Nothing has changed in the dockerfile so it's clearly something to do with the underlying environment, I have a Jenkins server running on AWS EC2. The strange thing is all the other packages are installing fine without any reference to R_HOME, it's just the XML package install that's failing

I've tried explicitly setting R_HOME in the dockerfile as per [this thread](https://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnet/issues/77) but no luck.

```
ENV R_HOME /usr/lib/R
```

**Jenkins stage**

```
stage ('Build docker image') {
    steps {                
        dir ('DockerImage') {
            sh 'docker-compose build'
        }
    }
}
```

**Jenkins console output**

```
Step 17/20 : RUN R -e "install.packages('XML')"
 ---> Running in cfc007e0ce94
[91mERROR: R_HOME ('/usr/lib/R') not found
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Run executable JAR in Linux

FROM cardcorp/r-java

# Set R and jri PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/bin/:/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/"

# Install packages in R
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('data.table', 'Rcpp', 'zoo'))"
RUN R -e "install.packages('foreach')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('doParallel')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('signal')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('bitops')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('matlab')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('GENEAread')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tuneR')"
RUN R -e "system('apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ABC')"
RUN R -e "system('apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XYZ')"
RUN R -e "system('apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc-8-base apt-transport-https')"
RUN R -e "system('apt-get install -y libxml2-dev')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('XML')"
```

**Edit:** Looking at the timestamp of when the issue started occurring, I spotted that there was a Debian release which coincides with my issue. I wonder if it's possible to specify the Debian version to use in the Docker file

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to set R_HOME, R will set it when it runs.  If you just leave out that `ENV  R_HOME /usr/lib/R` line, what happens?

Comment: @user2554330 the docker file I'm using is as defined above, without the line ENV R_HOME /usr/lib/R. I merely included this line as a way of trying to resolve the issue albeit this was unsuccessful anyway. So to answer you're question what happens without that line, I get the output shown in the code extract 'Jenkins Console Output'

Comment: That seems strange, because it refers to `/usr/lib/R` in the error message.  Can you print the value of the R function `R.home()`, and does it really contain `/usr/lib/R`?  Where is R really installed?

Comment: @user2554330 R_HOME prints out as "/usr/lib/R" up until line "RUN R -e "system('apt-get install -y libxml2-dev')" after which R_HOME can't be found so it that particular command seems to be clearing the system's environmental variables

Comment: @user2554330 in fact `RUN R -e "system('apt-get install -y libxml2-dev')` seems to be deleting `R` entirely from the environment as all `RUN R` commands fail thereafter with the `R_HOME` not found

Comment: Nobody suggested the simplest step:  `sudo apt install r-cran-xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I tracked the issue down to `test -x` not working. The `/usr/bin/R` script uses that to check if the `/usr/lib/R` folder exists.

Searching for solutions to this sent me to various bug reports in Ubuntu but I managed to resolve the issue by upgrading docker version. My Docker host is Centos not Ubuntu like in most bug reports, however my container is based on Ubuntu.

Things worked again after upgrading Docker to the following packages:

```
Upgraded:
  containerd.io-1.4.12-3.1.el8.x86_64
  docker-ce-3:20.10.12-3.el8.x86_64    
  docker-ce-cli-1:20.10.12-3.el8.x86_64  
  docker-scan-plugin-0.12.0-3.el8.x86_64

Installed:
  docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.12-3.el8.x86_64
  fuse-overlayfs-1.7.1-1.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64
  fuse3-3.2.1-12.el8.x86_64
  fuse3-libs-3.2.1-12.el8.x86_64
  libslirp-4.4.0-1.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64
  slirp4netns-1.1.8-1.module_el8.5.0+890+6b136101.x86_64
```

See:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1928218
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libseccomp/+bug/1916485

Comment: Very helpful - thanks!